# Setting up a summary table (Rails Associations)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble wrapping my head around what I'd consider a more complex association and was hoping someone could help point me in the right direction.

I have four models:

- user
- profile
- feed_group
- feed

All 4 of these obviously have their own fields and data stored within. My goal is to have a summary database table called "user_detail" (I am open to calling it something different if Rails has its conventions), which has the following 4 fields:

- user_id
- profile_id
- feed_group_id
- feed_id

What would my model associations look like?

Thanks.

Comment: How would you use this UserDetail?

Comment: Really trying to create a hub where user details are stored to keep track of feed groups and feeds associated with a profile. Trying to figure out how to store the data effectively and retrieve it.

Comment: Why not put the associations on the User model itself?

Comment: Because then the User model begins to house too much information. It would be more efficient to have a table like I'm describing to house the relationship between a user's feed groups and feeds. (Of which they can run CRUD on those associations).

Answer (score 1):

You can create the model through a migration like this:

```
rails g model UserDetail user:references profile:references feed_group:references feed:references
```

Within the created file `models/user_detail.rb` you will find the relations:

```
class UserDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profile
  belongs_to :feed_group
  belongs_to :feed
end
```

Also, add references to `UserDetail` in all the referenced models, eg. in `models/user.rb` add `has_many :user_details`, etc.

As I read your question, that's all you need.

Comment: Ok, this is what I thought. Taking it one step further then - say during the creation of this "Profile", I give them an opportunity to select a feed_group, call it "Tech". How do I make sure data gets inserted into the user_detail table? Nested forms?